# How to animate resetting of transform: rotate with CSS keyframes?

Tags: css, tailwind-css, css-animations

I created an animation for leafs to "wave". The leafs have some initial value for `rotate` from tailwind:

```css
@keyframes growSize {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    max-height: 0;
  }
  25% {
    max-height: 9999px;
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotate(5deg);
  }
  75% {
    transform: rotate(-5deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: none;
  }
}

.leaf-animation {
  animation-name: growSize;
  animation-delay: 2.5s;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.3.3"></script>

<div class="relative z-0 ml-32 mt-16 w-max">
  <img class="rounded-l-md rounded-r-3xl" src="https://placehold.co/308x392" width="308" height="392" />
  <svg viewBox="0 0 87 97" class="leaf-animation absolute -z-10 -rotate-45 w-20 -top-14 -left-14"><use href="#leaf" /></svg>
  <svg viewBox="0 0 87 97" class="leaf-animation absolute -z-10 -rotate-45 -scale-x-100 w-40 bottom-4 -left-32"><use href="#leaf" /></svg>
  <svg viewBox="0 0 87 97" class="leaf-animation absolute -z-10 rotate-45 w-36 bottom-32 -right-24"><use href="#leaf" /></svg>
</div>

<svg class="w-0 h-0" viewBox="0 0 87 97" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="leaf">
  <path d="M85.2 47C85.2 47 82.7 51.6 80.6 52.4C78.6 53.2 57.7 62.4 54.3 61.9C51 61.3 57.7 56.2 75.5 48.7C93.3 41.3 75.5 20.6 75.5 20.6L75.2 21.5C72.9 29.4 67.6 36.1 60.3 39.8C57.4 41.3 54.7 43.6 52.2 43C44.2 40.9 84.7 21.8 64.6 14.1C44.5 6.4 39.3 0.4 39.3 0.4C35.2 7.2 18.6 11.2 18.6 18.7C18.7 26.2 31.5 31.4 28.1 34.2C24.8 37.1 14.7 22.1 14.7 22.1C7.20003 28.6 6.70003 33.5 6.70003 33.5C10.1 47.9 31.2 57 21.7 56.2C7.40003 55 2.60003 43 2.60003 43C1.60003 47.4 0.600034 55.1 0.800034 62.3C1.10003 70.4 3.60003 78.2 8.20003 84.8C19.9 101.4 32.5 90.2 37.3 84.7V83C33 85.8 26.9 87.8 19.2 88.7C18.5 88.8 17.3 88.5 17.2 87.8C17.1 87.3 17.5 87 18.4 86.9C26.7 85.9 33 83.6 37.1 80.1C37.1 79.8 37.2 79.6 37.3 79.5C37.3 79.5 37.4 79.3 37.4 79.2V78.2C37.1 78.1 36.8 78 36.4 77.9C35.8 77.8 35.3 77.7 34.5 77.7C34.2 77.7 33.8 77.7 33.4 77.7C33 77.7 32.5 77.6 32.1 77.6H29.4C29 77.6 28.5 77.6 28.1 77.6C27.3 77.6 26.4 77.6 25.6 77.7C24.9 77.7 24.2 77.7 23.5 77.7C22.5 77.7 21.5 77.6 20.6 77.5C19.6 77.4 18.5 77.3 17.6 77.1L14.9 76.5C14.5 76.4 14.1 76.3 13.6 76.1C13.3 76 13.1 75.9 12.9 75.8C12.8 75.7 12.7 75.7 12.6 75.7H12C11.8 75.6 11.6 75.3 11.7 75.1C11.8 74.9 12.1 74.7 12.3 74.8L12.4 74.9C12.5 74.9 12.6 75 12.7 75C12.9 75 13.1 75.1 13.3 75.2C13.5 75.2 13.6 75.3 13.8 75.3L15 75.6C15.7 75.8 16.6 76 17.6 76.1C18.5 76.2 19.5 76.3 20.5 76.4C20.8 76.4 21.1 76.4 21.5 76.4C22.2 76.4 22.8 76.4 23.4 76.4C24.4 76.4 25.4 76.3 26.4 76.2C27.4 76.1 28.4 76 29.3 75.9C29.7 75.9 30.2 75.8 30.7 75.8C31.2 75.8 31.6 75.8 32 75.7C32.4 75.7 32.7 75.7 32.9 75.7C33.5 75.7 34 75.7 34.6 75.7C35.7 75.7 36.5 75.8 37.2 75.9L37.3 68.6C37.2 68.6 37.1 68.6 37 68.6C36.8 68.6 36.6 68.5 36.5 68.5C36.2 68.5 35.8 68.4 35.3 68.3C35 68.2 34.6 68.1 34.3 68C34 67.9 33.7 67.9 33.3 67.8C33 67.7 32.7 67.6 32.4 67.5C32 67.4 31.5 67.2 31 67.1L30.3 66.8C29.7 66.6 29 66.3 28.3 66C28 65.9 27.7 65.7 27.4 65.6C26.8 65.4 26.2 65.1 25.5 64.8C24.6 64.4 23.7 64 22.8 63.5C21 62.6 19.2 61.6 17.6 60.7C16.5 60.1 15.4 59.4 14.4 58.8C14 58.5 13.5 58.3 13.1 58C10.6 56.5 9.00003 55.4 9.00003 55.4C8.80003 55.2 8.70003 54.9 8.90003 54.7C9.10003 54.5 9.40003 54.4 9.60003 54.6C9.60003 54.6 11.3 55.7 13.9 57.2C14.3 57.4 14.7 57.6 15.1 57.9C16.1 58.4 17.2 59.1 18.4 59.6C20.1 60.5 21.9 61.3 23.7 62.1L26.4 63.3C27.3 63.7 28.2 64 29.1 64.3L29.8 64.5C30.4 64.7 31 64.9 31.6 65.1C32.4 65.3 33.2 65.5 33.9 65.7C34.5 65.9 35.1 66 35.6 66L36.2 66.1C36.6 66.2 37 66.2 37.3 66.2H37.4L37.6 52.4L37 52.3C36.6 52.2 36.2 52.1 35.8 51.9C35.3 51.7 34.7 51.5 34 51.3C33.6 51.2 33.2 51 32.8 50.8C32.5 50.7 32.3 50.5 32 50.4C31.6 50.2 31.2 50 30.8 49.7C30.5 49.5 30.2 49.3 29.8 49.2C29 48.7 28.2 48.2 27.5 47.8C26.8 47.3 26.1 46.8 25.3 46.2C24.9 45.9 24.6 45.6 24.2 45.3C23.8 45 23.5 44.7 23.1 44.4C22.8 44.1 22.4 43.8 22.1 43.5C21.8 43.2 21.5 42.9 21.2 42.7C21 42.5 20.8 42.3 20.6 42.1C20.2 41.7 19.8 41.4 19.5 40.9C19.3 40.7 19 40.4 18.8 40.1C18.6 39.8 18.3 39.6 18.1 39.3C16.4 37.3 15.4 35.9 15.3 35.8C15.1 35.6 15.2 35.3 15.4 35.1C15.6 34.9 15.9 35 16.1 35.2C16.1 35.2 17.2 36.6 19.1 38.5L20.6 40C20.8 40.2 21.1 40.4 21.3 40.6C21.6 40.9 22 41.2 22.3 41.5C22.9 42.1 23.6 42.6 24.3 43.1C25 43.6 25.7 44.1 26.4 44.7C27 45.1 27.8 45.6 28.5 46C28.8 46.2 29.2 46.4 29.5 46.6C29.9 46.8 30.3 47.1 30.6 47.2C30.9 47.3 31.2 47.5 31.5 47.6C31.9 47.8 32.3 48 32.7 48.1L33.2 48.3C33.7 48.5 34.2 48.7 34.7 48.9C35.3 49.1 35.9 49.3 36.4 49.4C36.8 49.5 37.3 49.6 37.6 49.7L38 28.3C37.9 28.2 37.9 28.2 37.8 28.1C37.7 28 37.6 28 37.5 27.9C37.4 27.8 37.4 27.8 37.3 27.7L37.2 27.6C37 27.4 36.8 27.2 36.6 27.1C36.3 26.9 36.2 26.7 36 26.5C35.9 26.4 35.8 26.3 35.7 26.2C35.4 25.9 35.2 25.7 35 25.4L34.8 25.2C34.5 24.9 34.3 24.5 34.1 24C33.9 23.6 33.7 23.3 33.5 23L33.4 22.9C33 22.1 32.6 21.3 32.3 20.5C32.2 20.2 32.1 19.9 32 19.6C31.8 19.2 31.7 18.7 31.5 18.4C31 17.2 30.9 16.2 30.9 16.2C30.9 15.9 31 15.7 31.3 15.7C31.5 15.6 31.8 15.8 31.9 16C31.9 16 32.2 16.8 32.7 18C32.8 18.2 32.9 18.4 33 18.6C33.2 19 33.4 19.5 33.7 20C34.1 20.7 34.5 21.4 35 22.1C35.2 22.3 35.3 22.4 35.4 22.6C35.5 22.8 35.6 22.9 35.7 23C35.9 23.2 36 23.3 36.1 23.5C36.2 23.6 36.3 23.8 36.5 23.9C36.6 24 36.7 24.1 36.8 24.2C36.9 24.4 37.1 24.5 37.2 24.6C37.4 24.7 37.5 24.9 37.7 25C37.8 25.1 37.9 25.2 38 25.3C38.1 25.4 38.1 25.4 38.2 25.4L38.4 6.1C38.4 5.8 38.6 5.6 38.9 5.6C39.2 5.6 39.4 5.8 39.4 6.1L39.7 39C39.8 38.9 39.9 38.9 40.1 38.8C40.4 38.7 40.6 38.6 40.9 38.4C41.4 38.2 42 37.9 42.6 37.6C42.8 37.5 43 37.4 43.2 37.3C43.6 37.1 44.1 36.9 44.6 36.6C45.3 36.2 46 35.8 46.7 35.3C47.4 34.8 48.1 34.3 48.9 33.8C49.5 33.2 50.3 32.6 51 32.1C51.6 31.6 52.3 31 52.9 30.3C53.1 30 53.4 29.7 53.7 29.5C54.1 29.1 54.4 28.8 54.7 28.4C55.3 27.7 55.8 27.1 56.2 26.4C56.6 25.9 57 25.3 57.4 24.5C57.5 24.2 57.7 24 57.8 23.7C58 23.4 58.2 23.1 58.3 22.8C58.6 22.2 58.8 21.7 58.9 21.5C59.3 20.7 59.4 20.3 59.4 20.3C59.5 20 59.7 19.9 60 19.9C60.3 20 60.4 20.2 60.4 20.4C60.4 20.4 60.3 21 60 21.7C59.9 21.9 59.9 22 59.8 22.2C59.7 22.5 59.6 22.8 59.4 23.2C59.2 23.7 58.9 24.3 58.6 24.9C58.3 25.5 57.9 26.2 57.5 26.9C57.1 27.6 56.6 28.3 56.1 29C55.6 29.7 55 30.4 54.4 31.1C53.8 31.9 53 32.6 52.4 33.2C52 33.5 51.7 33.8 51.3 34.2C50.9 34.5 50.6 34.9 50.2 35.2C49.6 35.7 49.1 36.1 48.5 36.6L47.8 37C47.1 37.5 46.4 38 45.6 38.4C44.9 38.8 44.2 39.2 43.6 39.6C42.9 40.1 42.2 40.4 41.8 40.5C41.6 40.6 41.3 40.8 41.1 40.9C40.9 41 40.7 41.1 40.6 41.2C40.2 41.4 39.9 41.6 39.6 41.7L39.8 58.5C39.9 58.5 40.1 58.5 40.2 58.4C40.3 58.4 40.5 58.3 40.7 58.3C40.8 58.3 41 58.3 41.1 58.2C41.4 58.1 41.8 58 42.2 57.9C42.9 57.6 43.8 57.3 44.7 57C45 56.9 45.4 56.7 45.8 56.6C46.4 56.3 47.1 56.1 47.7 55.8C48.3 55.5 48.8 55.3 49.4 55C50 54.7 50.5 54.4 51.1 54.2C51.4 54 51.7 53.8 52.1 53.6C52.9 53.2 53.7 52.7 54.6 52.3C55 52.1 55.4 51.8 55.9 51.5C56.6 51.1 57.3 50.6 58.1 50.1C58.6 49.7 59.2 49.3 59.8 48.9C60.4 48.5 60.9 48.2 61.5 47.8C62.6 47 63.7 46.2 64.7 45.4C65.7 44.6 66.7 43.8 67.6 43.1C68.3 42.6 69 42 69.6 41.4L70.1 41C73.1 38.2 75 36.2 75.1 36.1C75.3 35.9 75.6 35.9 75.8 36.1C76 36.3 76 36.6 75.9 36.8C75.9 36.8 74 38.8 71 41.7C70.7 42 70.4 42.2 70.2 42.5C69.7 43 69.1 43.5 68.5 44C67.6 44.8 66.7 45.6 65.7 46.4C65.3 46.7 65 47 64.6 47.3C63.9 47.8 63.3 48.4 62.5 48.9C62 49.3 61.4 49.7 60.8 50.2C60.3 50.6 59.7 51 59.2 51.4C58.2 52.1 57 52.9 55.8 53.7C54.6 54.4 53.5 55.1 52.4 55.8C52 56 51.6 56.2 51.3 56.4C50.6 56.8 49.8 57.3 49.1 57.6C48.8 57.8 48.4 57.9 48.1 58.1C47.4 58.4 46.7 58.8 46 59C45.3 59.3 44.7 59.5 44.2 59.7C43.9 59.8 43.6 59.9 43.3 60C43 60.2 42.7 60.3 42.4 60.3L42 60.5C41.6 60.6 41.3 60.7 41 60.8C40.6 60.9 40.2 61 40 61.1L40.1 72.8L40.5 72.7C41.1 72.6 41.8 72.5 42.7 72.4C43.5 72.3 44.5 72.1 45.4 71.9L46.1 71.8C46.9 71.6 47.8 71.5 48.8 71.2C49.5 71 50.4 70.8 51.2 70.6L52.4 70.3C53.2 70.1 54 69.9 54.8 69.6C55.3 69.4 55.7 69.3 56.2 69.1C57.5 68.7 58.8 68.2 60.1 67.7C60.7 67.5 61.4 67.2 62 66.9C62.6 66.6 63.3 66.3 63.9 66.1L67.5 64.3C68.5 63.7 69.7 63.1 70.6 62.4C71.1 62.1 71.5 61.8 71.9 61.5C72.4 61.1 72.9 60.8 73.4 60.5C74.2 59.9 75 59.3 75.7 58.8C76.1 58.5 76.5 58.2 76.8 57.9C77 57.7 77.2 57.6 77.4 57.4C77.6 57.2 77.9 57.3 78.1 57.5C78.3 57.7 78.3 58 78.1 58.2L78 58.3C77.8 58.5 77.6 58.7 77.3 58.9C77 59.2 76.7 59.5 76.4 59.8C76 60.2 75.6 60.5 75.2 60.8C74.9 61.1 74.5 61.3 74.2 61.6L73.8 62C73 62.6 72.2 63.2 71.2 63.8C70.6 64.2 70 64.6 69.3 65C68.9 65.3 68.5 65.5 68 65.8C66.9 66.5 65.7 67.1 64.5 67.7C63.1 68.4 61.8 69 60.6 69.4C60.2 69.6 59.7 69.7 59.3 69.9C58.4 70.3 57.5 70.6 56.7 70.9C55.9 71.1 55.1 71.4 54.4 71.7C53.9 71.9 53.4 72 52.9 72.2C52.4 72.3 52 72.5 51.5 72.6C50.7 72.8 50 73 49.3 73.3L48.3 73.5C47.4 73.7 46.6 73.9 45.9 74.1C45 74.4 44 74.6 43.1 74.7C42.5 74.8 41.9 74.9 41.4 75L41 75.1C40.7 75.1 40.5 75.2 40.2 75.2V78.8H40.4C41.6 78.9 43.2 79.1 45 79.4C46.5 79.6 48.3 79.8 50.1 80L51.6 80.2C52.2 80.2 52.7 80.3 53.3 80.4C53.9 80.5 54.6 80.6 55.3 80.6C56 80.7 56.7 80.7 57.4 80.8C58 80.9 58.6 80.9 59.1 81C60.4 81.1 61.7 81.2 62.9 81.2H64.8C65.4 81.2 66 81.2 66.5 81.1C66.9 81.1 67.2 81.1 67.4 81C67.7 81 68 80.9 68.3 80.9C68.8 80.9 69.2 80.8 69.7 80.7H69.9C71 80.6 72 80.4 73 80.2C73.5 80.1 73.9 80 74.2 79.8H74.3C74.5 79.8 74.7 79.7 74.8 79.6C75 79.5 75.2 79.4 75.4 79.4C76.1 79.1 76.7 78.8 77.1 78.6L77.5 78.3C77.8 78.1 78 78 78.1 77.9C78.3 77.7 78.6 77.7 78.8 77.9C78.9 78 78.9 78.1 78.9 78.3C78.9 78.5 78.9 78.6 78.8 78.7C78.6 78.9 78.2 79.2 77.7 79.5C77.4 79.7 77.1 79.9 76.7 80C76.4 80.1 76.1 80.3 75.8 80.5C75.6 80.6 75.3 80.7 75.1 80.8C74.9 80.9 74.7 80.9 74.5 81C74.1 81.2 73.7 81.3 73.3 81.4H73.1C72.2 81.7 71.1 81.9 70 82.1C69.5 82.2 69 82.3 68.4 82.4H68.3C67.7 82.5 67.1 82.6 66.4 82.6C66.2 82.6 65.8 82.7 65.5 82.7C65.2 82.7 64.9 82.7 64.6 82.8C64.2 82.8 63.9 82.8 63.6 82.9C63.3 82.9 62.9 83 62.6 83C61.7 83.1 60.9 83 60 83C59.6 83 59.1 83 58.7 83C57.4 83 56.1 82.9 54.8 82.8H54.5C53.3 82.7 52.2 82.6 51.1 82.6C49.1 82.4 47.2 82.3 45.5 82.3L44.5 82.2C43.7 82.2 42.9 82.1 42.2 82C41.9 82 41.6 82 41.3 81.9C41.6 82.2 41.9 82.6 42.2 83C42.2 83 42.3 83.1 42.4 83.2C42.5 83.3 42.7 83.5 42.8 83.6C43 83.7 43.1 83.9 43.3 84C43.4 84.1 43.5 84.2 43.6 84.3C44.2 84.8 44.8 85.3 45.5 85.7C46.2 86.2 46.8 86.6 47.7 87C48.5 87.4 49.3 87.8 50.1 88.1C53 89.2 56.5 90 59.6 90.3C62.3 90.6 64 90.6 64.1 90.6C64.4 90.6 64.6 90.8 64.6 91.1C64.6 91.4 64.4 91.6 64.2 91.6C64.1 91.6 62.3 91.8 59.6 91.7C58 91.6 53.8 91.3 49.7 89.9C48.9 89.6 48 89.3 47.1 88.9L44.7 87.7C44 87.3 43.2 86.8 42.5 86.3C42.3 86.2 42.2 86.1 42 85.9C41.9 85.8 41.7 85.7 41.6 85.6C41.3 85.4 40.9 85 40.7 84.8C40.5 84.6 40.3 84.4 40.2 84.3V84.4C43.1 91.8 47.1 101.9 69.5 93.5C94.2 84.2 85.2 47 85.2 47Z" fill="#3B613E" />
</svg>
```

I would like the wave animation to apply relative to their original rotation and reset the rotation to the initial value afterwards

Comment: Not a fix but note that the [<img>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/embedded-content.html#the-img-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `rotate-*` Tailwind utility classes apply `--tw-rotate` to form the rotation effect. We can piggy-back off this and use the same CSS variable in the `@keyframes`, and using `calc()` to change the rotation relative to this:

```css
@keyframes growSize {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(var(--tw-rotate, 0deg));
    max-height: 0;
  }
  25% {
    max-height: 9999px;
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotate(calc(var(--tw-rotate, 0deg) + 5deg));
  }
  75% {
    transform: rotate(calc(var(--tw-rotate, 0deg) - 5deg));
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(var(--tw-rotate, 0deg));
  }
}

.leaf-animation {
  animation-name: growSize;
  animation-delay: 2.5s;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.3.3"></script>

<div class="relative z-0 ml-32 mt-16 w-max">
  <img class="rounded-l-md rounded-r-3xl" src="https://placehold.co/308x392" width="308" height="392" />
  <svg viewBox="0 0 87 97" class="leaf-animation absolute -z-10 -rotate-45 w-20 -top-14 -left-14"><use href="#leaf" /></svg>
  <svg viewBox="0 0 87 97" class="leaf-animation absolute -z-10 -rotate-45 -scale-x-100 w-40 bottom-4 -left-32"><use href="#leaf" /></svg>
  <svg viewBox="0 0 87 97" class="leaf-animation absolute -z-10 rotate-45 w-36 bottom-32 -right-24"><use href="#leaf" /></svg>
</div>

<svg class="w-0 h-0" viewBox="0 0 87 97" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="leaf">
  <path d="M85.2 47C85.2 47 82.7 51.6 80.6 52.4C78.6 53.2 57.7 62.4 54.3 61.9C51 61.3 57.7 56.2 75.5 48.7C93.3 41.3 75.5 20.6 75.5 20.6L75.2 21.5C72.9 29.4 67.6 36.1 60.3 39.8C57.4 41.3 54.7 43.6 52.2 43C44.2 40.9 84.7 21.8 64.6 14.1C44.5 6.4 39.3 0.4 39.3 0.4C35.2 7.2 18.6 11.2 18.6 18.7C18.7 26.2 31.5 31.4 28.1 34.2C24.8 37.1 14.7 22.1 14.7 22.1C7.20003 28.6 6.70003 33.5 6.70003 33.5C10.1 47.9 31.2 57 21.7 56.2C7.40003 55 2.60003 43 2.60003 43C1.60003 47.4 0.600034 55.1 0.800034 62.3C1.10003 70.4 3.60003 78.2 8.20003 84.8C19.9 101.4 32.5 90.2 37.3 84.7V83C33 85.8 26.9 87.8 19.2 88.7C18.5 88.8 17.3 88.5 17.2 87.8C17.1 87.3 17.5 87 18.4 86.9C26.7 85.9 33 83.6 37.1 80.1C37.1 79.8 37.2 79.6 37.3 79.5C37.3 79.5 37.4 79.3 37.4 79.2V78.2C37.1 78.1 36.8 78 36.4 77.9C35.8 77.8 35.3 77.7 34.5 77.7C34.2 77.7 33.8 77.7 33.4 77.7C33 77.7 32.5 77.6 32.1 77.6H29.4C29 77.6 28.5 77.6 28.1 77.6C27.3 77.6 26.4 77.6 25.6 77.7C24.9 77.7 24.2 77.7 23.5 77.7C22.5 77.7 21.5 77.6 20.6 77.5C19.6 77.4 18.5 77.3 17.6 77.1L14.9 76.5C14.5 76.4 14.1 76.3 13.6 76.1C13.3 76 13.1 75.9 12.9 75.8C12.8 75.7 12.7 75.7 12.6 75.7H12C11.8 75.6 11.6 75.3 11.7 75.1C11.8 74.9 12.1 74.7 12.3 74.8L12.4 74.9C12.5 74.9 12.6 75 12.7 75C12.9 75 13.1 75.1 13.3 75.2C13.5 75.2 13.6 75.3 13.8 75.3L15 75.6C15.7 75.8 16.6 76 17.6 76.1C18.5 76.2 19.5 76.3 20.5 76.4C20.8 76.4 21.1 76.4 21.5 76.4C22.2 76.4 22.8 76.4 23.4 76.4C24.4 76.4 25.4 76.3 26.4 76.2C27.4 76.1 28.4 76 29.3 75.9C29.7 75.9 30.2 75.8 30.7 75.8C31.2 75.8 31.6 75.8 32 75.7C32.4 75.7 32.7 75.7 32.9 75.7C33.5 75.7 34 75.7 34.6 75.7C35.7 75.7 36.5 75.8 37.2 75.9L37.3 68.6C37.2 68.6 37.1 68.6 37 68.6C36.8 68.6 36.6 68.5 36.5 68.5C36.2 68.5 35.8 68.4 35.3 68.3C35 68.2 34.6 68.1 34.3 68C34 67.9 33.7 67.9 33.3 67.8C33 67.7 32.7 67.6 32.4 67.5C32 67.4 31.5 67.2 31 67.1L30.3 66.8C29.7 66.6 29 66.3 28.3 66C28 65.9 27.7 65.7 27.4 65.6C26.8 65.4 26.2 65.1 25.5 64.8C24.6 64.4 23.7 64 22.8 63.5C21 62.6 19.2 61.6 17.6 60.7C16.5 60.1 15.4 59.4 14.4 58.8C14 58.5 13.5 58.3 13.1 58C10.6 56.5 9.00003 55.4 9.00003 55.4C8.80003 55.2 8.70003 54.9 8.90003 54.7C9.10003 54.5 9.40003 54.4 9.60003 54.6C9.60003 54.6 11.3 55.7 13.9 57.2C14.3 57.4 14.7 57.6 15.1 57.9C16.1 58.4 17.2 59.1 18.4 59.6C20.1 60.5 21.9 61.3 23.7 62.1L26.4 63.3C27.3 63.7 28.2 64 29.1 64.3L29.8 64.5C30.4 64.7 31 64.9 31.6 65.1C32.4 65.3 33.2 65.5 33.9 65.7C34.5 65.9 35.1 66 35.6 66L36.2 66.1C36.6 66.2 37 66.2 37.3 66.2H37.4L37.6 52.4L37 52.3C36.6 52.2 36.2 52.1 35.8 51.9C35.3 51.7 34.7 51.5 34 51.3C33.6 51.2 33.2 51 32.8 50.8C32.5 50.7 32.3 50.5 32 50.4C31.6 50.2 31.2 50 30.8 49.7C30.5 49.5 30.2 49.3 29.8 49.2C29 48.7 28.2 48.2 27.5 47.8C26.8 47.3 26.1 46.8 25.3 46.2C24.9 45.9 24.6 45.6 24.2 45.3C23.8 45 23.5 44.7 23.1 44.4C22.8 44.1 22.4 43.8 22.1 43.5C21.8 43.2 21.5 42.9 21.2 42.7C21 42.5 20.8 42.3 20.6 42.1C20.2 41.7 19.8 41.4 19.5 40.9C19.3 40.7 19 40.4 18.8 40.1C18.6 39.8 18.3 39.6 18.1 39.3C16.4 37.3 15.4 35.9 15.3 35.8C15.1 35.6 15.2 35.3 15.4 35.1C15.6 34.9 15.9 35 16.1 35.2C16.1 35.2 17.2 36.6 19.1 38.5L20.6 40C20.8 40.2 21.1 40.4 21.3 40.6C21.6 40.9 22 41.2 22.3 41.5C22.9 42.1 23.6 42.6 24.3 43.1C25 43.6 25.7 44.1 26.4 44.7C27 45.1 27.8 45.6 28.5 46C28.8 46.2 29.2 46.4 29.5 46.6C29.9 46.8 30.3 47.1 30.6 47.2C30.9 47.3 31.2 47.5 31.5 47.6C31.9 47.8 32.3 48 32.7 48.1L33.2 48.3C33.7 48.5 34.2 48.7 34.7 48.9C35.3 49.1 35.9 49.3 36.4 49.4C36.8 49.5 37.3 49.6 37.6 49.7L38 28.3C37.9 28.2 37.9 28.2 37.8 28.1C37.7 28 37.6 28 37.5 27.9C37.4 27.8 37.4 27.8 37.3 27.7L37.2 27.6C37 27.4 36.8 27.2 36.6 27.1C36.3 26.9 36.2 26.7 36 26.5C35.9 26.4 35.8 26.3 35.7 26.2C35.4 25.9 35.2 25.7 35 25.4L34.8 25.2C34.5 24.9 34.3 24.5 34.1 24C33.9 23.6 33.7 23.3 33.5 23L33.4 22.9C33 22.1 32.6 21.3 32.3 20.5C32.2 20.2 32.1 19.9 32 19.6C31.8 19.2 31.7 18.7 31.5 18.4C31 17.2 30.9 16.2 30.9 16.2C30.9 15.9 31 15.7 31.3 15.7C31.5 15.6 31.8 15.8 31.9 16C31.9 16 32.2 16.8 32.7 18C32.8 18.2 32.9 18.4 33 18.6C33.2 19 33.4 19.5 33.7 20C34.1 20.7 34.5 21.4 35 22.1C35.2 22.3 35.3 22.4 35.4 22.6C35.5 22.8 35.6 22.9 35.7 23C35.9 23.2 36 23.3 36.1 23.5C36.2 23.6 36.3 23.8 36.5 23.9C36.6 24 36.7 24.1 36.8 24.2C36.9 24.4 37.1 24.5 37.2 24.6C37.4 24.7 37.5 24.9 37.7 25C37.8 25.1 37.9 25.2 38 25.3C38.1 25.4 38.1 25.4 38.2 25.4L38.4 6.1C38.4 5.8 38.6 5.6 38.9 5.6C39.2 5.6 39.4 5.8 39.4 6.1L39.7 39C39.8 38.9 39.9 38.9 40.1 38.8C40.4 38.7 40.6 38.6 40.9 38.4C41.4 38.2 42 37.9 42.6 37.6C42.8 37.5 43 37.4 43.2 37.3C43.6 37.1 44.1 36.9 44.6 36.6C45.3 36.2 46 35.8 46.7 35.3C47.4 34.8 48.1 34.3 48.9 33.8C49.5 33.2 50.3 32.6 51 32.1C51.6 31.6 52.3 31 52.9 30.3C53.1 30 53.4 29.7 53.7 29.5C54.1 29.1 54.4 28.8 54.7 28.4C55.3 27.7 55.8 27.1 56.2 26.4C56.6 25.9 57 25.3 57.4 24.5C57.5 24.2 57.7 24 57.8 23.7C58 23.4 58.2 23.1 58.3 22.8C58.6 22.2 58.8 21.7 58.9 21.5C59.3 20.7 59.4 20.3 59.4 20.3C59.5 20 59.7 19.9 60 19.9C60.3 20 60.4 20.2 60.4 20.4C60.4 20.4 60.3 21 60 21.7C59.9 21.9 59.9 22 59.8 22.2C59.7 22.5 59.6 22.8 59.4 23.2C59.2 23.7 58.9 24.3 58.6 24.9C58.3 25.5 57.9 26.2 57.5 26.9C57.1 27.6 56.6 28.3 56.1 29C55.6 29.7 55 30.4 54.4 31.1C53.8 31.9 53 32.6 52.4 33.2C52 33.5 51.7 33.8 51.3 34.2C50.9 34.5 50.6 34.9 50.2 35.2C49.6 35.7 49.1 36.1 48.5 36.6L47.8 37C47.1 37.5 46.4 38 45.6 38.4C44.9 38.8 44.2 39.2 43.6 39.6C42.9 40.1 42.2 40.4 41.8 40.5C41.6 40.6 41.3 40.8 41.1 40.9C40.9 41 40.7 41.1 40.6 41.2C40.2 41.4 39.9 41.6 39.6 41.7L39.8 58.5C39.9 58.5 40.1 58.5 40.2 58.4C40.3 58.4 40.5 58.3 40.7 58.3C40.8 58.3 41 58.3 41.1 58.2C41.4 58.1 41.8 58 42.2 57.9C42.9 57.6 43.8 57.3 44.7 57C45 56.9 45.4 56.7 45.8 56.6C46.4 56.3 47.1 56.1 47.7 55.8C48.3 55.5 48.8 55.3 49.4 55C50 54.7 50.5 54.4 51.1 54.2C51.4 54 51.7 53.8 52.1 53.6C52.9 53.2 53.7 52.7 54.6 52.3C55 52.1 55.4 51.8 55.9 51.5C56.6 51.1 57.3 50.6 58.1 50.1C58.6 49.7 59.2 49.3 59.8 48.9C60.4 48.5 60.9 48.2 61.5 47.8C62.6 47 63.7 46.2 64.7 45.4C65.7 44.6 66.7 43.8 67.6 43.1C68.3 42.6 69 42 69.6 41.4L70.1 41C73.1 38.2 75 36.2 75.1 36.1C75.3 35.9 75.6 35.9 75.8 36.1C76 36.3 76 36.6 75.9 36.8C75.9 36.8 74 38.8 71 41.7C70.7 42 70.4 42.2 70.2 42.5C69.7 43 69.1 43.5 68.5 44C67.6 44.8 66.7 45.6 65.7 46.4C65.3 46.7 65 47 64.6 47.3C63.9 47.8 63.3 48.4 62.5 48.9C62 49.3 61.4 49.7 60.8 50.2C60.3 50.6 59.7 51 59.2 51.4C58.2 52.1 57 52.9 55.8 53.7C54.6 54.4 53.5 55.1 52.4 55.8C52 56 51.6 56.2 51.3 56.4C50.6 56.8 49.8 57.3 49.1 57.6C48.8 57.8 48.4 57.9 48.1 58.1C47.4 58.4 46.7 58.8 46 59C45.3 59.3 44.7 59.5 44.2 59.7C43.9 59.8 43.6 59.9 43.3 60C43 60.2 42.7 60.3 42.4 60.3L42 60.5C41.6 60.6 41.3 60.7 41 60.8C40.6 60.9 40.2 61 40 61.1L40.1 72.8L40.5 72.7C41.1 72.6 41.8 72.5 42.7 72.4C43.5 72.3 44.5 72.1 45.4 71.9L46.1 71.8C46.9 71.6 47.8 71.5 48.8 71.2C49.5 71 50.4 70.8 51.2 70.6L52.4 70.3C53.2 70.1 54 69.9 54.8 69.6C55.3 69.4 55.7 69.3 56.2 69.1C57.5 68.7 58.8 68.2 60.1 67.7C60.7 67.5 61.4 67.2 62 66.9C62.6 66.6 63.3 66.3 63.9 66.1L67.5 64.3C68.5 63.7 69.7 63.1 70.6 62.4C71.1 62.1 71.5 61.8 71.9 61.5C72.4 61.1 72.9 60.8 73.4 60.5C74.2 59.9 75 59.3 75.7 58.8C76.1 58.5 76.5 58.2 76.8 57.9C77 57.7 77.2 57.6 77.4 57.4C77.6 57.2 77.9 57.3 78.1 57.5C78.3 57.7 78.3 58 78.1 58.2L78 58.3C77.8 58.5 77.6 58.7 77.3 58.9C77 59.2 76.7 59.5 76.4 59.8C76 60.2 75.6 60.5 75.2 60.8C74.9 61.1 74.5 61.3 74.2 61.6L73.8 62C73 62.6 72.2 63.2 71.2 63.8C70.6 64.2 70 64.6 69.3 65C68.9 65.3 68.5 65.5 68 65.8C66.9 66.5 65.7 67.1 64.5 67.7C63.1 68.4 61.8 69 60.6 69.4C60.2 69.6 59.7 69.7 59.3 69.9C58.4 70.3 57.5 70.6 56.7 70.9C55.9 71.1 55.1 71.4 54.4 71.7C53.9 71.9 53.4 72 52.9 72.2C52.4 72.3 52 72.5 51.5 72.6C50.7 72.8 50 73 49.3 73.3L48.3 73.5C47.4 73.7 46.6 73.9 45.9 74.1C45 74.4 44 74.6 43.1 74.7C42.5 74.8 41.9 74.9 41.4 75L41 75.1C40.7 75.1 40.5 75.2 40.2 75.2V78.8H40.4C41.6 78.9 43.2 79.1 45 79.4C46.5 79.6 48.3 79.8 50.1 80L51.6 80.2C52.2 80.2 52.7 80.3 53.3 80.4C53.9 80.5 54.6 80.6 55.3 80.6C56 80.7 56.7 80.7 57.4 80.8C58 80.9 58.6 80.9 59.1 81C60.4 81.1 61.7 81.2 62.9 81.2H64.8C65.4 81.2 66 81.2 66.5 81.1C66.9 81.1 67.2 81.1 67.4 81C67.7 81 68 80.9 68.3 80.9C68.8 80.9 69.2 80.8 69.7 80.7H69.9C71 80.6 72 80.4 73 80.2C73.5 80.1 73.9 80 74.2 79.8H74.3C74.5 79.8 74.7 79.7 74.8 79.6C75 79.5 75.2 79.4 75.4 79.4C76.1 79.1 76.7 78.8 77.1 78.6L77.5 78.3C77.8 78.1 78 78 78.1 77.9C78.3 77.7 78.6 77.7 78.8 77.9C78.9 78 78.9 78.1 78.9 78.3C78.9 78.5 78.9 78.6 78.8 78.7C78.6 78.9 78.2 79.2 77.7 79.5C77.4 79.7 77.1 79.9 76.7 80C76.4 80.1 76.1 80.3 75.8 80.5C75.6 80.6 75.3 80.7 75.1 80.8C74.9 80.9 74.7 80.9 74.5 81C74.1 81.2 73.7 81.3 73.3 81.4H73.1C72.2 81.7 71.1 81.9 70 82.1C69.5 82.2 69 82.3 68.4 82.4H68.3C67.7 82.5 67.1 82.6 66.4 82.6C66.2 82.6 65.8 82.7 65.5 82.7C65.2 82.7 64.9 82.7 64.6 82.8C64.2 82.8 63.9 82.8 63.6 82.9C63.3 82.9 62.9 83 62.6 83C61.7 83.1 60.9 83 60 83C59.6 83 59.1 83 58.7 83C57.4 83 56.1 82.9 54.8 82.8H54.5C53.3 82.7 52.2 82.6 51.1 82.6C49.1 82.4 47.2 82.3 45.5 82.3L44.5 82.2C43.7 82.2 42.9 82.1 42.2 82C41.9 82 41.6 82 41.3 81.9C41.6 82.2 41.9 82.6 42.2 83C42.2 83 42.3 83.1 42.4 83.2C42.5 83.3 42.7 83.5 42.8 83.6C43 83.7 43.1 83.9 43.3 84C43.4 84.1 43.5 84.2 43.6 84.3C44.2 84.8 44.8 85.3 45.5 85.7C46.2 86.2 46.8 86.6 47.7 87C48.5 87.4 49.3 87.8 50.1 88.1C53 89.2 56.5 90 59.6 90.3C62.3 90.6 64 90.6 64.1 90.6C64.4 90.6 64.6 90.8 64.6 91.1C64.6 91.4 64.4 91.6 64.2 91.6C64.1 91.6 62.3 91.8 59.6 91.7C58 91.6 53.8 91.3 49.7 89.9C48.9 89.6 48 89.3 47.1 88.9L44.7 87.7C44 87.3 43.2 86.8 42.5 86.3C42.3 86.2 42.2 86.1 42 85.9C41.9 85.8 41.7 85.7 41.6 85.6C41.3 85.4 40.9 85 40.7 84.8C40.5 84.6 40.3 84.4 40.2 84.3V84.4C43.1 91.8 47.1 101.9 69.5 93.5C94.2 84.2 85.2 47 85.2 47Z" fill="#3B613E" />
</svg>
```